# Support for Loadinf procedure

Tags: inno-setup

i would need some assistance with this [loadinf function](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/fcd29a583579acfe092e0c0bbf5503872d3957ec/Projects/Main.pas#L618)

```
const
  Section = 'Setup';

  procedure LoadInf(const FileName: String; var WantToSuppressMsgBoxes: Boolean);
var
  S: String;
begin
  //saved infs
  InitLang := GetIniString(Section, 'Lang', InitLang, FileName);
  InitDir := GetIniString(Section, 'Dir', InitDir, FileName);
  InitProgramGroup := GetIniString(Section, 'Group', InitProgramGroup, FileName);
  InitNoIcons := GetIniBool(Section, 'NoIcons', InitNoIcons, FileName);
  InitSetupType := GetIniString(Section, 'SetupType', InitSetupType, FileName);
  S := GetIniString(Section, 'Components', '$', FileName);
  if S <> '$' then begin
    InitComponentsSpecified := True;
    SetStringsFromCommaString(InitComponents, SlashesToBackslashes(S));
  end;
  S := GetIniString(Section, 'Tasks', '$', FileName);
  if S <> '$' then begin
    InitDeselectAllTasks := True;
    SetStringsFromCommaString(InitTasks, SlashesToBackslashes(S));
  end; 
end;
```

I'm having issues with the 
`SetStringsFromCommaString(InitComponents, SlashesToBackslashes(S));`

Is there any way to do that function in inno ?

The `SetStringsFromCommaString` can be found [here](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/SetupTypes.pas#L124) , but couldn't make it to compile

Best Regards, 
 BeGiN.

Comment: Err, do what function ? Are you asking how to fill a string list with a comma separated string or something ?

Comment: yes , something like that ... if i have the following [INI File](http://pastebin.com/dcHDypy0) and i call the loadinf function `      LoadInf(Expandconstant('{userdesktop}\tada.ini'),Supress);` it should load into the installer that information ( As the \LOADINF Param ) but in code :)